# Phonegap Build Universal cordova.js? Windows iOS using Build Service

Tags: cordova

Main issue is that I'm developing an app for Android and iOS but can't seem to find the correct .js file for iOS.. I don't have Xcode or anything either :\

I think this might be in development but in the past (a year ago) when I started using phonegap I would include one `phonegap.js` file and build would compile it for multiple differnt platforms. Now it seems that I have to have the correct `cordova.js` file and I'm having trouble doing so.

Is there some sort of a "universal" .js file that I can use?

How would a windows user use Build to produce an iOS application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that if you're using the phonegap build service you can simply include phonegap.js (and you don't need to download anything) and the cloud takes care of it for you.

Comment: does this still work for you ? you just reference cordova.js and it works?

Answer (score 0):

There has never been a universal phonegap.js each platform has always had it's own version of phonegap.js. Because of the move to Apache the file is now cordova.js.

Comment: so how would you use build? 
It seems I was able to get it to work by just using "phonegap.js" (which isn't even something I actually downloaded) but the Build service did it for me?